# Is it possible in Go to pass pointer of string and make it slice of string?

Tags: pointers, go, slice, dereference

So basically I was wondering if it possible in GO, because I was playing with *Dereference*.

For example in Code shown below. Pointer is passed to function and I'm trying to return one letter of passed pointer string, in given example that is H, but however *slice* can only be used with strings. And I was wondering if it possible to do this using pointer Dereference.

**Code Example:**

```
func Test(test *string) {
    if len(*test) > 0 {
        *test = *test[:1]
    }
    strings.ToUpper(*test)
}

func main() {
  str := "hello"
    Test(&str)
  fmt.Print( str)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place `test` in brackets, i.e. dereference the pointer first, and then slice it.

Then the `Test` function still wouldn't return capital `H` though, because `ToUpper` takes and returns a value. So you need to reassign the output of `ToUpper` to `*test` as well:

```
func Test(test *string) {
    if len(*test) > 0 {
        *test = (*test)[:1] // bracketed `test`
    }
    *test = strings.ToUpper(*test) // reassign to `test`
}

func main() {
  str := "hello"
    Test(&str)
  fmt.Print(str) // Prints 'H'
}
```

[Go Play example](https://play.golang.org/p/69mUVP-6AjS)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible in Go to pass pointer of string and make it slice of string?

Yes: `func (ps *string) []string { return []string{*ps} }`

Comment: So basically there is no way to make it without using return statement ? I was curious if it could be done only with pointer dereference

Comment: Actually I have no idea what you are actually trying to do. Your question is pretty unclear.

Comment: Well, I'm passing string pointer to function, then if string is not empty, I'm taking one letter of string using slice. Using only string: `func (str string) string {}`, but i want to do it with pointer dereference

Comment: @TiPSY  really have no idea what your are talking about. `*test[:1]` is not a slice it is a index expression on a string which produces a string and not a slice. It does not matter whether you pass a string or a string pointer. Please clarify the question.